# Why use Task.Run to create a new task around a simple async method call?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

This is a pattern I'm seeing in some code I'm working on:

```
result = await Task.Run(async () => await MyAsynchronousMethod());
```

and I'm failing to see what this does that this does not do:

```
result = await MyAsynchronousMethod();
```

What is the former construction here intended to accomplish?

Comment: `Task.Run()` runs code in a background thread. `await` does not.

Comment: Couldn't the second `await` in the first example be removed entirely?

Comment: @DiskJunky Only if you remove `async` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Task.Run` starts a task on the thread pool that will execute the `async` method. So in the first case, the `async` method itself will be called on a background thread.

In the second case, the `MyAsynchronousMethod` method will run synchronously, just like any other non-async method, on the calling thread until it hits an `await`. This *might* block the calling thread, at least for a while, depending on how the async method is implemented.

There are examples of poorly implemented `async` methods that blocks the calling thread *before* they hit an `await` and calling such a method on the dispatcher thread in a UI application may for example freeze the application.